# How to dynamically update content (markers) on the MapView to another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-mapview, marker

I'm interested in the problem - how it is possible to update the content (markers) on the map when they are added to the other thread. The problem lies in the fact - that I add markers to the map in the other thread, partly to avoid slowing down the user interface, because that is necessary to create a marker to analyze the database. It seems that the program works properly - but after the markers were set up, they do not check the map. In order to display them to make interaction with the card (touch or change of scale). Here's why I want to ask - is it possible to update the contents of the map by adding a marker? Initiate a change of scale in my not a good solution. I hope for your help.

***UPDATE, BUT NOT WORK ***

```
public void onPostExecute(){                     
                     SQLiteDatabase placeDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/expir.java.file/databases/PlaceDataBase",
                            null ,
                            0);             
                     Cursor location_latitude = placeDataBase.query("AllInfo",new String[]{"LOCATION_LATITUDE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                     location_latitude.moveToFirst();
                     Log.d("CREATE CURSOR 1", "lat");
                     Cursor location_longitude = placeDataBase.query("AllInfo", new String[]{"LOCATION_LONGITUDE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                     location_longitude.moveToFirst();
                     Cursor location_name = placeDataBase.query("AllInfo", new String[]{"LOCATION_NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                     location_name.moveToFirst();
                     Cursor vicinity = placeDataBase.query("AllInfo", new String[]{"VICINITY"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                     vicinity.moveToFirst();
                     Cursor id = placeDataBase.query("AllInfo", new String[]{"&&&&&&&&"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                     id.moveToFirst();
                     Log.d("CREATE CURSOR 2", "lon");
                     quantityPlace = location_latitude.getCount();
                     int a = 0;
                     for(int i=1;i<=quantityPlace;i++){
                        if((int)(location_latitude.getDouble(0)*1000000)>=myLocationLatitude-(3*8998)&&
                                (int)(location_latitude.getDouble(0)*1000000)<=myLocationLatitude+(3*8998)&&
                                (int)(location_longitude.getDouble(0)*1000000)>=myLocationLongitude-(6*8998)&&
                                (int)(location_longitude.getDouble(0)*1000000)<=myLocationLongitude+(6*8998)){
                            a++;
                            Drawable drawable1 = MyMapActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scoutgroup);                      
                            itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable1, MyMapActivity.this);                           ;
                            GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint((int)(location_latitude.getDouble(0)*1000000), (int)(location_longitude.getDouble(0)*1000000));                                                          
                            overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point1, location_name.getString(0), vicinity.getString(0));
                            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
                        }
                        Log.d("INFO", location_latitude.getPosition()+"/"+quantityPlace);
                        location_latitude.moveToPosition(i);
                        location_longitude.moveToPosition(i);
                        location_name.moveToPosition(i);
                        vicinity.moveToPosition(i);
                        id.moveToPosition(i);
                     }
                     Log.d("On map view", a+" location(s)");
                                     mapView.invalidate();
                     placeDataBase.close();
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Java's usual multithreading concepts, consider using Android's. AsyncTask is designed for your kind of need.

Do what you need with your database in its doInBackground() method, and notify your mapview with fresh data from onPostExecute() method.

Also, don't forget to call mapview.invalidate() to redraw your fresh markers.

Comment: weird - but in a previous implementation (in Listing) line mapView.invalidate () causes an error.  E/AndroidRuntime(5120): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  Thanks for the answer I will try to do what you recommend.

Comment: I tried to implement the suggested approach - but it did not work - using mapView.invalidate () app crashes and logs indicate the reason for this:                 E/AndroidRuntime(3594): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                   I tried to make the addition of markers in the onPostExecute(), but it often means that nothing is added at all,  though all the people on the forums write that it is necessary to manipulate it in this method because doInBackground()  has no access to UI.

Answer (score 0):

again, you haven't listen to what I said. Any work related to the database, should be done in `doInBackground()` method. any UI related work should be done in `onPostExecute()` method.

try `mapOverlays.clear()` before you add your itemized overlay

Comment: No - I correctly understood - I just thought that this division to the database and add markers to be too resource-intensive because of the need of intermediate variables. Now I try to implement exactly what you said.